# Praat script to extract .wav and corresponding TextGrid for all tokens of a specific word

Tags: praat

I'm not competent in Praat scripting and am wondering if someone could help me with what I believe should be a pretty simple task.

I'm looking to extract `.wav` and TextGrids for all tokens of a given word in a directory of recordings (tier 1 is phone, tier 2 word). Ideally, I'd also like to include whatever word follows the word of interest in this extraction.

Does anyone have a script that would be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not write all the script. I will steer you towards two different scripts. You will can mix them to achieve your aim.

Try this script: https://lennes.github.io/spect/scripts/save_selection_to_sound_and_textgrid.praat

And this one:

---

```
numberOfTiers = Get number of tiers

for i to numberOfTiers

#determine number of intervals of current tier

numberOfIntervals = Get number of intervals: i

#loop through all intervals of current tier and extract labels one by one

for j to numberOfIntervals

label$ = Get label of interval: i, j

appendInfoLine: label$

endfor

endfor
```

---